# The begin and end time of windows

Tags: flink-streaming

What would be the way to show the begin and end time of windows? something like implement user-defined windows?

Would like to know the time that windows begin and evaluate such that the output is

```
quantity(WindowAll Sum), window_start_time, window_end_time
12, 1:13:21, 1:13:41
6, 1:13:41, 1:15:01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. `TimeWindow.class` has getStart() and getEnd()

example usage:

```
public static class SumAllWindow implements AllWindowFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>,
        Tuple3<Integer, String, String>, TimeWindow> {

    private static transient DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS").withLocale(Locale.GERMAN).
                    withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));

    @Override
    public void apply (TimeWindow window, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> values,
                       Collector<Tuple3<Integer, String, String>> out) throws Exception {

        DateTime startTs = new DateTime(window.getStart(), DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
        DateTime endTs = new DateTime(window.getEnd(), DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));

        int sum = 0;
        for (Tuple2<String, Integer> value : values) {
            sum += value.f1;
        }
        out.collect(new Tuple3<>(sum, startTs.toString(timeFormatter), endTs.toString(timeFormatter)));
    }
}
```

in main()

```
msgStream.timeWindowAll(Time.of(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).apply(new SumAllWindow()).print();
```